# Detect source code syntax type of a given byte

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting

I would like to detect the syntax type of source-code (in my use-case of HTML/Javascript/PHP (those 3 can be mixed in a single file!), C and SQL-dumps).

I would like to detect whether a given byte-range (or single byte) in a source-code file is inside of a string, whether that string is defined with single-quotes or double-quotes (as is legal in PHP) and whether the bytes are inside a comment.

Is there something out there that can do that?

Comment: No. Given any string inside a larger one, you cannot determine whether quotes at either end are "inside" or "outside" quotes (i.e., whether  you are "in" a string).

Comment: Not without more context. You'd need a full blown parser, keeping track of each string entry and exit along the way. You wouldn't be able to take a random byte and know whether you are in a string, but you would be able to process each byte and mark each as in string based on the context within which it is found.

Comment: @Ron: Of course a parser would be needed, but I guess there are dozens of parsers for syntax-highlighting and maybe one of those is able to remember what byte is what syntax type.